# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Login Redirection Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I am new to ASP.NET Core and have started with ASP.NET Core 3.1. I am trying to implement login.

For this, I have used the default template option that allows for "Allow Individual Accounts" that is check marked during the creation of the project. I have integrated [IdentityManagerUI](https://github.com/mguinness/IdentityManagerUI) for the Users, Roles and Claims Management.

I have also "scaffolded" and overridden all the logins and related pages to customize the UI according to the theme I am using.

Here is the startup class:

```
    Public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
     
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()               
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {                   
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
            });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        });
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

**Problem**

Each time I try to log in the request is redirected back to the Login page. I tried to set up break points at

1. OnGetAsync
2. OnPostAsync

I have noticed the contents of the login model are appended to the URL and never posted to `OnPostAsync`. The request is never posted to the action `OnPostAsync` and `OnGetAsync` gets called each time.

Any guidance regarding this and why this is happening would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you paste code from your login actions and login form.

Comment: @PlamenYordanov The code is the default scaffolded code available with the asp.net core MVC templates. I haven't modified the code.  Just the UI in _Layout and nothing else.